# Attach DataTemplate to Xamarin.Forms ShellContent

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm succesfully attaching a DataTemplate to my FlyoutItems and MenuItems in my Xamarin.Forms Shell App. However, how do I attach the same template to the ShellContent?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
       xmlns:volDash="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.VolDash"
       xmlns:orgDash="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.OrgDash"
       x:Class="EventingVolunteers.AppShell"
       FlyoutBackgroundColor="#337ab7">
    <Shell.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FlyoutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FlyoutTemplates">
            <Grid HeightRequest="{x:OnPlatform Android=50}" Style="{StaticResource FlyoutItemStyle}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:OnPlatform Android=54, iOS=50}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    HeightRequest="{x:OnPlatform Android=24, iOS=22}"
                    WidthRequest="{x:OnPlatform Android=24, iOS=22}">
                </Image>
                <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                        FontSize="{x:OnPlatform Android=14, iOS=Small}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label.TextColor>
                        White
                    </Label.TextColor>
                    <Label.Margin>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="20, 0, 0, 0" />
                            </OnPlatform.Platforms>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.Margin>
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="sans-serif-medium" />
                            </OnPlatform.Platforms>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.Resources>
    <FlyoutItem
        x:Name="volFlyoutItem"
        Title="Volunteer Dashboard"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem"
        FlyoutIcon="ic_dashboard_white.png"
        Shell.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplates}">
        <ShellContent Title="Signups" Icon="ic_assignment.png">
            <volDash:SignupsPage />
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent Title="Events" Icon="ic_event.png">
            <volDash:AreasPage />
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent Title="Mailbox" Icon="ic_mail_outline.png">
            <volDash:MailboxPage />
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent Title="Rankings" Icon="fa_trophy.png">
            <volDash:MyRankingsPage />
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent Title="Videos" Icon="ic_ondemand_video.png">
            <volDash:TrainingVideoCategoriesPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem
        x:Name="orgFlyoutItem"
        Title="Organizer Dashboard"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem"
        FlyoutIcon="ic_dashboard_white.png"
        IsEnabled="False"
        Shell.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplates}">
        <ShellContent Title="Events" Icon="ic_event.png">
            <orgDash:EventsPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Account"
        Icon="ic_account_box_white.png"
        Shell.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplates}"
        Shell.MenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplates}">
        <views:AccountPage />
    </ShellContent>
    <MenuItem
        Shell.MenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplates}"
        Text="Logout"
        Icon="ic_dashboard_white.png"
        Command="{Binding LogOutCommand}" />
</Shell>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell has implicit conversion operators that enable the Shell visual hierarchy to be simplified, without introducing additional views into the visual tree. This is possible because a subclassed `Shell` object can only ever contain `FlyoutItem` objects or a `TabBar` object, which can only ever contain `Tab` objects, which can only ever contain `ShellContent` objects. These implicit conversion operators can be used to remove the `FlyoutItem`, `Tab`, and `ShellContent` objects.

In your xaml,the `ShellContent` is a simplification of `<FlayoutItme> <ShellContent/></FlayoutItme>`,so you just need to add `<FlayoutItme>` outside it and add `Shell.ItemTemplate`.

```
<FlyoutItem
    x:Name="account"
    Title="Account"
    FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem"
    FlyoutIcon="ic_account_box_white.png"
    Shell.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplates}">
    <ShellContent>
        <views:AccountPage />
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```